# I'm having trouble getting my beta ready android app out in Google play

Tags: android, mobile

So I've went through all the steps to upload my .apk to the Google dev console, and I've added my Google group for the list of people that will be testing it. Then it asked me to publish my app so I can get the opt- in link to send to my testers. I'm supposed to be able to send out a non production ready app to beta testers, but when I try to set up the beta channel, it wants me to publish my app and wants it to be production ready. Can anybody walk me through the steps of setting up my beta app so I can get the opt in link to send to my Google group?

Answer (score 0):

Just upload your Beta into the Beta channel. You actually have to publish the app. This only publishes the Beta for your testers, not a production channel.

So the steps usually are:

- upload apk into Beta
- paste the link to your community/Google group
- publish the app (top right corner)
- grab the opt-in link and send it to your testers
- send a Play Store link or the signed apk to your testers

This takes like 2-24 hours for your testers to see the app in the Play Store. Some of my testers still don't see the app after 4 days.. Seems not completely reliable, yet.

Hope this helps. Have fun :)

Comment: So here is the spot I am at, I, for the life of me, can not find the "publish the app" button.

http://imgur.com/TjSCe14

Comment: @JarredAnthonyDouthit to right corner, click on "Draft". Should be there :)